# How can I get a vba Excel code (with .dll) working in vb.net?

Tags: vba, vb.net, dll

I have a working code in VBA Excel, that calls a function from a .dll file.

```
Private Declare Function SJ Lib "C:\MyDLL.dll" (ByRef p1 As Double, ByRef p2 As Variant, ByRef p3 As Double) As Boolean
```

I can run this function and receive the result as variant.
However, when I try to use this code in VB.NET I am unable to get a result back because the application crashes during the call of this function.

This is what I've tried:

```
 Public Declare Function SJ Lib "C:\MyDLL.dll" (ByRef p1 As Double, ByRef p2 As Object, ByRef p3 As Double) As Boolean
```

I have also tried:

```
    <DllImport("C:\MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall,
CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Public Function SJ(ByRef p1 As Double, ByRef p2 As Object, ByRef p3 As Double) As Boolean
End Function
```

I also tried running the code in x86, but that also doesn't work.

Any tips?

Comment: Was there any error message?

Comment: Yes:
The program '[50336] myProgram.exe' has exited with code -1073741403 (0xc00001a5)

Comment: The function call causes a fastfail, there's no exception handler that can handle the internal error. Your dll may be incompatible or what you're passing, or the way you're doing it, is really not what is expected. -- You should probably describe how that dll is built, what actual values that function is expecting (for sure not an `object`) and why you have all those `ByRef` there.

Comment: @jimi 
I don't have the code behind the .dll file. in VBA Excel I send:

    `Dim aInputData(100) As Double
    Dim aResult(100) As Variant
    Dim aOptions(1) As Variant`

These arrays are then modified by the .dll function.